# how to use multiple table with multiple select tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, foreach

I have two container with class product-sizes. each of these contines a select option with two Measurement inch and cm. each of these options shows inch table and hide cm and opposit.

with just one product-sizes my jquery works fine but with two or more I have problem. tables don't trigger well between inch and cm and NO.2 container even did't show the tabel.

can anyone tell how should I fix this.
also if you know about vanilla js I liked to know how to do it with js
or if you have some other solution it would be nice.

```js
$('.product-sizes').each(function () {
    $(this).find('.measurement').on('change', function () {
      $('.product-sizes__tab').hide();
      $('.product-sizes__tab').eq($(this).val()).show();
    }).trigger('change');
  });
```

```css
.product-sizes{
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding: 15px 6px 6px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #E6E6E6;
    border-radius: 12px;
}
.product-sizes__head{
    padding: 0 16px;
}
.product-sizes__head--title{
    font-size: 16px;
    color: black
}
.measurement{
    padding: 7px 10px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #E6E6E6;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
.measurement,
.measurement select:focus>option:checked{
    color: blue;
}
.measurement--label{
    font-size: 16px;
    color: black
}
.product-sizes__tab{
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
.product-sizes__tab--th,
.product-sizes__tab--td{
    min-width: 200px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin: 8px 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.product-sizes__tab--th,
.product-sizes__tab .product-sizes__tab--td:not(:first-child){
    text-align: center;
}
.product-sizes__tab--th{
    padding: 10px 8px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: black;
    background: #E6E6E6;
}
.product-sizes__tab--td{
    padding: 10px 8px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="product-sizes">
          <div class="product-sizes__head d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <h3 class="product-sizes__head--title">Available Sizes:</h3>
            <form class="d-flex align-items-center">
              <label for="measurement" class="measurement--label me-3">Measurement:</label>
              <select class='measurement'>
                  <option value='1'>inches</option>
                  <option value='2'>centimeters</option>
              </select>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="product-sizes__tabs">
            <div class="product-sizes__tab active" id="tab1">
              <ul class="d-flex">
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--th col">Item \ Size</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--th col">Length</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--th col">Suction Line</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--th col">Liquid Line</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--th col">Insulation Wall Thickness</li>
              </ul>
              <ul class="d-flex">
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col" style="color: #7C4686; border-left: 6px solid #9B58A7;">CO50381438W</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col">50'</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col">3/8"</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col">1/4"</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col">3/8"</li>
              </ul>
              <ul class="d-flex">
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col" style="color: #7C4686; border-left: 6px solid #9B58A7;">CO50381438W</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col">50'</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col">3/8"</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col">1/4"</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col">3/8"</li>
              </ul>
              <ul class="d-flex">
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col" style="color: #7C4686; border-left: 6px solid #9B58A7;">CO50381438W</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col">50'</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col">3/8"</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col">1/4"</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col">3/8"</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="product-sizes__tab" id="tab2">
              <ul class="d-flex">
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--th col">Item \ Size</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--th col">Length</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--th col">Suction Line</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--th col">Liquid Line</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--th col">Insulation Wall Thickness</li>
              </ul>
              <ul class="d-flex">
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col" style="color: #7C4686; border-left: 6px solid #9B58A7;">CO50381438W</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col">cm</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col">cm</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col">cm</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col">cm</li>
              </ul>
              <ul class="d-flex">
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col" style="color: #7C4686; border-left: 6px solid #9B58A7;">CO50381438W</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col">cm</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col">cm</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col">cm</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col">cm</li>
              </ul>
              <ul class="d-flex">
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col" style="color: #7C4686; border-left: 6px solid #9B58A7;">CO50381438W</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col">50'</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col">3/8"</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col">1/4"</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col">3/8"</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
                <div class="product-sizes">
          <div class="product-sizes__head d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <h3 class="product-sizes__head--title">Available Sizes:</h3>
            <form class="d-flex align-items-center">
              <label for="measurement" class="measurement--label me-3">Measurement:</label>
              <select class='measurement'>
                  <option value='1'>inches</option>
                  <option value='2'>centimeters</option>
              </select>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="product-sizes__tabs">
            <div class="product-sizes__tab active" id="ali1">
              <ul class="d-flex">
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--th col">Item \ Size</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--th col">Length</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--th col">Suction Line</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--th col">Liquid Line</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--th col">Insulation Wall Thickness</li>
              </ul>
              <ul class="d-flex">
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col" style="color: #7C4686; border-left: 6px solid #9B58A7;">CO50381438W</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col">50'</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col">3/8"</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col">1/4"</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col">3/8"</li>
              </ul>
              <ul class="d-flex">
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col" style="color: #7C4686; border-left: 6px solid #9B58A7;">CO50381438W</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col">50'</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col">3/8"</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col">1/4"</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col">3/8"</li>
              </ul>
              <ul class="d-flex">
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col" style="color: #7C4686; border-left: 6px solid #9B58A7;">CO50381438W</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col">50'</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col">3/8"</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col">1/4"</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col">3/8"</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="product-sizes__tab" id="ali2">
              <ul class="d-flex">
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--th col">Item \ Size</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--th col">Length</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--th col">Suction Line</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--th col">Liquid Line</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--th col">Insulation Wall Thickness</li>
              </ul>
              <ul class="d-flex">
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col" style="color: #7C4686; border-left: 6px solid #9B58A7;">CO50381438W</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col">cm</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col">cm</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col">cm</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col">cm</li>
              </ul>
              <ul class="d-flex">
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col" style="color: #7C4686; border-left: 6px solid #9B58A7;">CO50381438W</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col">cm</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col">cm</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col">cm</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col">cm</li>
              </ul>
              <ul class="d-flex">
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col" style="color: #7C4686; border-left: 6px solid #9B58A7;">CO50381438W</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col">50'</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col">3/8"</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col">1/4"</li>
                <li class="product-sizes__tab--td col">3/8"</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close with your code. You just need to make sure to capture the container element so you can do the showing/hiding in and only in the intended `.product-sizes` container.

I like your idea of looping over each `.product-sizes`, but I will grab a reference to the element. In the `change` handler, I will use that reference to loop through the tabs that are descendants of the affected container. I will use jQuery's [.toggle](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle) method to determine whether or not to show the tab, based on its index.

The final code looks like:

```
$('.product-sizes').each(function () {
  const $container = $(this);
  
  $container.on('change', '.measurement', function () {
    // subtract 1 b/c array index are 0-based
    const activeTabIndex = Number($(this).val()) - 1;

    $container.find('.product-sizes__tab').each(function () {
      const $this = $(this);
      const isActive = $this.index() === activeTabIndex;
      
      $this.toggle(isActive);
      $this.toggleClass('active', isActive);
    })
  });
});
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/0aLg5y6c/) is an example fiddle.

I think if you have already got jQuery loaded, then it is best to use jQuery over vanilla JS. The vanilla version would be heavier and less readable.

Comment: works fine on fiddle but if I make change that product-sizes number two to just have a simple table and remove the select from it the first one will effects. how to make flexible of this problem?

Comment: @Alipvd How is the first table affected in this case? The `change` listeners are independent of each other and affect only their containers, so I do not see how one can affect the other. See: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/csy8vpqn/